# Web hosting control panel to integrate with AWS to work on huge magento site

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using "Amazon web service". we are planning to devolop huge magento site.

I wanted to know which is the best user-friendly "Web hosting control panel" to work on magento site.

Many suggested to  use cpanel. what's the cost of cpanel.

IS is better to continue with cpanel or to go with another "Web hosting control panel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a Magento related question. I am not sure how long your question is going to remain here. And for the answer, here you go.

cPanel is the best. You can see the pricing here: http://cpanel.net/plans-pricing/

If you are looking for free ones, try the open-source control panel Webmin
http://www.webmin.com

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.

in the link that you provided, is i have to choose which of the following option.

VPS Cost  
Dedicated Cost  
CloudLinux Cos

we bought amazon web service licence.

Comment: AWS is cloud. So you should be looking at CloudLinux

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. please help me  with this : is we have to pay for "Amazon web service" to give disk space to store "cpanel[20gb ] and other storages"?

or Amazon web service[EC2] provide free storage?

Answer (score 1):

Control panels like Plesk/Cpanel/Webmin are for simple, single server setups to provide a rounded set of tools (web/email/dns etc). It won't support multiple servers or be at all capable of scaling horizontally.

If you don't have experience with managing a large scale, horizontally scaled platform without the help of a control panel - then AWS and other DIY service is absolutely the wrong choice.

You don't need a control panel, you need a managed hosting provider!

Comment: Agreed - if you are building a 'huge' Magento site then presumably you are trying to achieve 'huge' traffic. In that case roll your own is a really bad idea. Get some capable managed hosting and decent sysadmin on board.

Comment: hi choco, thanks a lot for reply. 

which hosting provider [integrated with cpanel ] you will prefer better than a "aws"?

Comment: hi Jonathan, thanks a lot for reply. 

which hosting provider [integrated with cpanel ] you will prefer better than a "aws"?

Comment: I can't make recommendations, but my advice would certainly be to not restrict yourself to a cPanel provider. Any company providing cPanel is almost certainly not likely to be a focused Magento hosting provider. cPanel lacks expertise to deploy, its there for easy server management, not high performance or scalability.